# How do I migrate Google Chrome bookmarks from XP to Ubuntu?

Tags: google-chrome, installed-programs

I've just swtiched from XP to Ubuntu. I've installed Google Chrome to Ubuntu. I have my XP Chrome folder on an external hard drive including the bookmarks file. I was thinking I could just go to the Ubuntu equivalent of 'Program Files' and switch in my XP Chrome bookmarks folder for the Ubuntu default one, but I have had no luck in finding such a place as 'Program Files' in Ubuntu.

```
1. Where is the Ubuntu equivalent to Windows XP's 'Program Files'?
2. How do I migrate Google Chrome bookmarks from XP to Ubuntu?
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Xp, get in to the google chrome bookmarks manager and select export bookmarks as HTML file.
Copy your bookmarks.html file you created to a external memory.

Get in to the Ubuntu Google Chrome, open bookmarks manager and select Import bookmarks from HTML file and load them.

They will be located to the Imported Bookmarks folder in google chrome.

p.s: There is no Program Files folder in Ubuntu.
You should type the below command to the terminal to see the binary files you can run within Ubuntu

```
sudo $PATH
```

Installation and execution process is different on Linux Machines.

Comment: sudo: /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games: command not found

Comment: Unfortunately I already uninstalled XP. Maybe I can do it from an XP emulator? Or, maybe I can convert the txt file to a html by myself and that will work?

Comment: You can try to import your bookmarks from the XP Chrome folder on your external drive. But the bookmarks file extension is important.